# "m2e plugin execution not covered..." with parent project configuration

Tags: maven, plugins, m2e

I have dealt with jslint-maven-plugin getting caught by the infamous "plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration" error by adding an ignore action to the pom, as per [Eclipsepedia advice](http://wiki.eclipse.org/M2E_plugin_execution_not_covered#lifecycle_mapping_metadata_provided_by_maven_plugin).

Works great, if I have the pluginManagement section in the project's pom, or in a parent project pom in my local workspace.

However, it breaks again as if I hadn't applied the fix if the parent is not in my local workspace, despite the effective pom still showing the additional config. The build works fine from the command line, it just seems to be the IDE UI that's not working correctly.

Any ideas why this might be happening and how I could resolve the problem?

Maven 3.0.3 and m2e 1.0.200.